# jQuery "val" Check Value of QTY input field and display error if is greater than stock available

Tags: jquery

I have a small jQuery problem, I can echo with PHP how many of a certain product is in stock. I would like to use jQuery to check the input and if the value is higher than the amount in stock then there to be a red warning popup.

```
<script>
jQuery("input").keyup(function () {
var value = jQuery(this).val();
if( value > <?php echo $stock_qty ?> )
jQuery( '#stock-info-block' ).show();
}).keyup();
</script>

<div class="stock-info-block" style="display: none;">
<p><?php echo $this->__('Sorry we only have %d left in Stock', $stock_qty); ?></p>
</div>
```

I have this but it doesn't seem to be working, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var myStock = <?php echo $stock_qty ?> ;
    jQuery("input").keyup(function () {
        var value = jQuery(this).val();
        if (value > myStock) 
            jQuery('#stock-info-block').show();
    }).keyup();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add the script in dom ready

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("input").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if( value > <?php echo $stock_qty ?> )
            $( '#stock-info-block' ).show();
    }).keyup();
})
```